# BSOD bugcheck event viewer output

Tags: bsod

My computer just booted from a memory management BSOD and I found this in the event viewer:

> The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was:
>   0x0000001a (0x0000000000006000, 0xffffe401f79883f0,
>   0xffffffffc0000225, 0x0000000000000000). A dump was saved in:
>   C:\WINDOWS\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id:
>   c840a976-1092-4dc8-b9fe-7906ebdbba7c.

Is this good, bad, fixable, or fatal?

Answer (score 0):

See:  https://www.thewindowsclub.com/memory-management-error-0x0000001a

> If your Windows PC crashes all of a sudden with a Blue Screen error
>   message MEMORY_MANAGEMENT accompanied by Stop Code 0x0000001A, then
>   chances are that its a hardware problem you have encountered. It can
>   be either an issue with RAM or Hard disk or malware taking up all
>   memory on your PC,

It could be a Root Kit virus.  Try TDSS Killer and see if that is the issue.  Otherwise it is a hardware issue.  Try one only memory module if you have two memory modules to test memory. Otherwise, you may need to get it serviced

TDSS Killer: https://usa.kaspersky.com/downloads/tdsskiller